# The length size of linked list using recursion in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I encounter some question on recursion of the linked list during self-studying. Any help is appreciated.

I understand that the variable named "data" store the current number and the "next" store the address of the next class, which contains the next number and an address.

By my understanding, recursion is the function calling itself and needs a base case in order to stop itself or the program will encounter the problem of stack overflowing. However, the following code in a linked list program in C++ does not have a base case, so whenever the function is called, does this means the function will make finite nodes and stop when the stack is overflown? If so, does this also means the linked list has a length limitation?

```
class Node {

    int data;    //store the current vaule
    Node *next;  //the address of the next value

}
```

Comment: Usually the last `Node` in the list will have its `next` set to `nullptr` - that is the base case you can check for.

Comment: right, so if node == null, return 0, else return recursive_length(node->next) + 1;

Comment: Unless you are positive, that the length of the list is (very) limited in all cases, you should not  use recursion to traverse the list. Generally speaking, there are no tail calls in C++ (while some compilers might bend that a little). And unless it is just some mental exercise, you would much rather use a ``std::forward_list<T>`` and stick to C++ standard library ``iterator`` idioms.

Comment: So when I call the function at the beginning without setting the null pointer, does this means the function will actually make finite nodes until the stack is overflown. Could I interpret the null pointer is used to trim the size of the linked list?

Comment: Leaving a raw pointer uninitialized is good for any bad effects - not only concerning your specific issue... Concerning [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure) (to which `int` and raw pointers belong to) in `class`es, I always have an "extra" eye as the implicit construction is leaving them uninitialized. That can cause you real head-aches as soon as the project has grown to a certain amount of code...

Comment: The base case could be set with a null pointer in the class using the following code?

Node (int x){

data=x;
Next = nullptr;

}

Comment: There is no function that gets called in the code you posted, so it's very unclear what missing base case you're referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't initialise the members of a `Node`, then any use of it is undefined behaviour.

You would typically *define* `nullptr` as meaning "there are no more elements", and any valid pointer as meaning "there are more elements", and write your functions using that definition, taking care to never have invalid pointer values.

This is all assuming you are coding as a learning exercise. If you aren't, you'd use `std::vector` instead of writing a container yourself.